# How do I get this list to be seperated by a tab? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I've just started with HTML/CSS, and I decided to start with something simple, like a nav bar. But the thing is all the tutorials online only go up to this point (below code) and **completely** ignore how to put a space between each list item. I've tried adding width, but it makes an *uneven* space. Could someone please show me how to do this? Thanks!

Here's my code; a working model is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7gzLvqn9/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="bannercontent">
            <ul id="banner">
                <li id="bannerlinks"><a id= "links" href="#">What We Do </a></li>
                <li id="bannerlinks"><a id= "links" href="#"> Pricing </a></li>
                <li id="bannerlinks"><a id= "links" href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                <li id="bannerlinks"><a id= "links" href="#"> Wholesale</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </body>            
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300);
    #bannercontent{
    font-family: 'Quicksand:300';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#banner{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#links{
    text-decoration: none;  
}
#bannerlinks
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a margin value on li elements:

```
li { margin-right: 20px; }
```

This will add a space of 20px between all li elements.

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7gzLvqn9/1/)***

Please note: `id`s are supposed to be unique, `class`es are made for adding the same style to similar elements, so instead of `<li id="bannerlinks">` it should be `<li class="bannerlinks">`. In your CSS you need to update `#bannerlinks` to `.bannerlinks`.

Comment: thanks, it worked!
I'll accept ur answer when it lets me

Comment: Please see my added note regarding ids and classes.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about classes. Sorry! Thanks for the reminder - it made my code a *whole* lot bettter

Answer (score 1):

I will second the concept of class usage over id.
For the purpose of your question, I did not change that, but was able to get results using a padding on your bannerlink elements:

```
#bannerlinks
{
    display: inline;
    padding: .5em;
}
```

You can tweak the number to set spacing as wide as you want, for example 5em forced it to multiple lines in the JSFiddle window.